# Porting my MonoGame app to Windows Store/UWP

Tags: windows, uwp, monogame

I have my MonoGame app working great with cross-platform/OpenGL.  Now I want to port it to Windows Store so I can make some sales, but I'm running into some confusion.

1. I don't know why in the top left corner of my game window and in the top right corner of my monitor window there is a black debugging box with numbers in it.

   I'm guessing that the top right corner might be the framerate but I'm not sure what the other numbers are. I'd prefer to disable it.

   I also have no idea what this widget in the top middle of my game window is and what it's supposed to do. If it's important, I'd like to know what its purpose is. If not, I'd like to disable it.

Comment: A couple or remarks: First: Ask one question per... question in Stack overflow. Otherwise it is too broad for an aswer. Second: Try to format them so that they are easy to read. I can only answer the first one: those numbers are a FPS counter declared on the entry point of the application. They are only shown in debug mode and you can just comment the code that shows it.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the numbers like following then you are right. They are related to the frame rate.
[image]

The numbers displayed in the top left corner of your app are **App fps** and **App CPU**. And the numbers displayed in the top right corner of your monitor are **Sys fps** and **Sys CPU**.

> - ***App fps:*** The app's UI thread frame rate, in frames per second.
> - ***App CPU:*** The CPU usage of the app's UI thread per frame, in milliseconds.
> - ***Sys fps:*** The system-wide composition engine frame rate, in frames per second. This is typically pegged to 60.
> - ***Sys CPU:*** The system-wide overall CPU usage of the composition thread per frame, in milliseconds.

To disable it, you can set [`DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.debugsettings.enableframeratecounter.aspx) to **false**. Or just comment out following code in app.xaml.cs:

```cs
#if DEBUG
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
    }
#endif
```

For more info, please see the **Remarks** in [DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.debugsettings.enableframeratecounter.aspx).

And for the widget in the top middle of your app, it's [**In-App Menu**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx#misc) for XAML Diagnostics.

> Visual Studio 2015 now has an In-App Menu that makes it easier to perform UI Debugging. You can turn the selection mode on and off, toggle the layout adorners, and jump directly to the Live Visual Tree in Visual Studio. You can also collapse the In-App Menu by clicking on the bars below the icons, or turn the In-App Menu on and off from the Live Visual Tree.

It's usually used to inspect XAML properties while debugging. For more info, you can refer to [Inspect XAML properties while debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx). You can close it by clicking the first button in **"Live Visual Tree"**.
[image]

And to disable it, you can open <kbd>**Tools**</kbd> → <kbd>**Options**</kbd> → <kbd>**Debugging**</kbd> → <kbd>**General**</kbd> → <kbd>**Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML**</kbd> then uncheck "**Show runtime tools in application**".
[image]